# Mapping domain entities into PetaPoco models

Tags: c#, asp.net, petapoco, onion-architecture

I'm using Onion Architecture and PetaPoco micro-orm at my infrastructure layer. How can I  map a domain entity from core layer to a petapoco object to access the data via petapoco?

Comment: Check this link might be useful :http://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/posts/115-PetaPoco-Mapping-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-One-Relationships

Comment: normal domain entity to core layer mapping you can access through automapper package

Comment: Automapper FTW. https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html